# Scrapy in python - save within the parse function -thread safe?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to download pages. I would like to save all the downloaded pages in a single file. I have the following code for the constructor and parse:

```
    def __init__(self):
        self.time = time_utils.get_current_time_hr()
        self.folder = f"{ROOT_DIR}/data/tickers/scrapy/{self.time}/"
        os.makedirs(self.folder, exist_ok=True)
        filename = self.folder + "bigfile.txt"
        self.f = open(filename, 'w')

    def parse(self, response):
        buffer = list()
        buffer.append(response.body.decode("utf-8") )
        self.f.write("".join(buffer))
        self.f.flush()
```

Is there a possibility that different html pages will be mixed in the big_file.txt I'm writing?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Isn't having different html pages saved in the bif_file.txt the goal?

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy is single threaded, but even if the data won't get corrupted it's still a bad idea because writing to a file is a blocking operation.

You can use [FEEDS](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#std-setting-FEEDS) and let it handle it for you.

Try this example and see if it OK for what you need:

**main.py:**

```py
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

if __name__ == "__main__":
    spider = 'example_spider'
    settings = get_project_settings()
    settings['USER_AGENT'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'
    settings['FEEDS'] = {
        'bigfile.csv': {
            'format': 'csv',
            # if you use 'overwrite' = True, it will overwrite the file with each item it yields.
        }
    }
    process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
    process.crawl(spider, start_urls=['https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/list_basic/?page=2'])
    process.crawl(spider, start_urls=['https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/list_basic/?page=4'])
    process.start()
```

**spider.py:**

```py
import scrapy


class ProductSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "example_spider"

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        yield {response.url: response.body.decode("utf-8")}
```